# RStudio Server error when restarting the R session

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

This recently began to appear whenever I restart my RStudio Server session:

```
Error in tools:::httpdPort > 0 : 
  comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

It does not seem to relate to running any code (all I do to reproduce it is to go to the Session menu and then click "Restart R"). It appears that we are running version 0.97.551.

What is this error and how can we resolve it?

Comment: does `traceback()` show anything?

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed.  Try updating everything to the latest version.

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/202656007-Cryptic-error-on-starting-RStudio-daily-with-R-devel

[What does "Error in tools:::httpdPort <= 0L : ...." in Rstudio means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32924328/what-does-error-in-toolshttpdport-0l-in-rstudio-means)