# Internet routines cannot be loaded

Tags: r, rstudio

I have Windows XP and I wanted to upgrade my RStudio version to the latest. When I did it, I installed a version which didn't support XP and it didn't work. I uninstalled it and install the 0.98.1103 version of RStudio. But I have this message when running it or writing something related to internet.

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) -- "Bug in Your Hair"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Error in tools::startDynamicHelp() : internet routines cannot be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
R graphics engine version 11 is not supported by this version of RStudio.
The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed.
```

When I do `?help` I get `starting httpd help server ...Error in startDynamicHelp(TRUE) : internet routines cannot be loaded`.

Sorry for my english... but how can I fix this?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Can you try `Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")`, a similar issue was mentioned here [previously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218590/error-in-install-packages-internet-routines-cannot-be-loaded-using-statet-while)

Comment: @Ossan I did it and I get `Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")
[1] ""`

Comment: RStudio help function checks for consistency between R version and RStudio version. This error occurs when you are trying to use latest R version with older version of RStudio. Only way to resolve is to downgrade your R version to one that is supported by RStudio 0.98.1103.  More information at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32924328/what-does-error-in-toolshttpdport-0l-in-rstudio-means)

Comment: RStudio v0.98.1103 is relatively old at this point, and only works up to R 3.2.x. You will likely need to upgrade RStudio or downgrade R.

Comment: Thanks for posting - I have the same problem, following the upgrade of  RStudio to 1.1.441 and R to 3-4.4 (from 3-4.0) on my windows XP. NB: both RStudio and R are the latest versions (as of today). Help no longer works (e.g. `?Startup` gives `starting httpd help server ...Error in startDynamicHelp(TRUE) : internet routines cannot be loaded`).

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and wasted lot of time on it. Actually, I installed R and RStudio, however also had Anaconda installed.
After couple of hours it seemed that Anaconda and separate installation of RStudio was having some issue.
I uninstalled R and RStudio from my machine and installed RStudio via Anaconda.
Please note: first I created Virtual environment by selecting R in Anaconda Navigator and then installed RStudio inside Anaconda.
Now starting RStudio inside Anaconda works like a charm!
[Link -- > Steps to install RStudio inside Anaconda

(please note to uninstall R and RStudio previous installations from your machine)](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/create-r-environment/)